# Why do const variables don't need to be initialized in a template class until the class is actually used?

Tags: c++, templates, constants

Why doesn't the compiler throw an error if I don't initialize `const` variables in an unused template class? If I remove the `template` keyword the compiler complains as expected.

This code works (unexpected):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class Matrix {
private:
    const uint8_t numRows, numColumns;
    T content[];

public:
    Matrix(uint8_t numRows, uint8_t numColumns) 
    // : numRows(numRows), numColumns(numColumns) -- Works fine
    {
        std::cout << "Matrix" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    // If Matrix constructor is not called the compiler doesn't need a initialization list
    // Matrix<int> matrix(2, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

But this one does not (expected):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class Matrix {
private:
    const uint8_t numRows, numColumns;
    T content[];

public:
    Matrix(uint8_t numRows, uint8_t numColumns)
    // : numRows(numRows), numColumns(numColumns) -- Does NOT work
    {
        std::cout << "Matrix" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Matrix<int> matrix(2, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: generally templates do not have to generate any errors if unused - it is up to compiler. Clang/GGC perform some static analysis on templates while MSVC doesn't do any.

Comment: Note that all questions in terms of "why this in c++" have the initial answer "because the C++ standard says so". Then you may wonder about the motivations of the C++ committee when designing that part of the standard :)

Comment: Part of your confusion might be due to "template class". The Standard intentionally uses "class template" to make clear that only an instantiation of a class template is a class. The class template itself is a template, not a class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Class template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template#Implicit_instantiation) isn't implicitly instantiated until required. You don't use `Matrix<int>`, then it's not instantiated, and definition is not required (to exist or to be well-formed).

> When code refers to a template in context that requires a completely defined type, or when the completeness of the type affects the code, and this particular type has not been explicitly instantiated, implicit instantiation occurs. For example, when an object of this type is constructed, but not when a pointer to this type is constructed.

From the standard, [[temp.inst]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.inst#2):

> Unless a class template specialization is a declared specialization, the class template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires a completely-defined object type or when the completeness of the class type affects the semantics of the program.

[[temp.inst]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.inst#11):

(emphasis mine)

> An implementation shall not implicitly instantiate a function template, a variable template, a member template, **a non-virtual member function**, a member class or static data member of a templated class, or a substatement of a constexpr if statement ([stmt.if]), unless such instantiation is required.

So in this case, the ill-formed `Matrix<T>::Matrix(uint8_t numRows, uint8_t numColumns)` is not allowed to be implicitly instantiated.

Comment: Doesn't http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res.general-6.1 make it ill-formed NDR?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat There might be specialization as `Matrix<int>` which is well-formed. We can't judge that the code is ill-formed just because the primary template is. https://wandbox.org/permlink/LJKpqqQjIn4UoBCZ

Comment: could you clarify: A comment on the question suggests that here the compiler is not required to issue an error, but I think the compiler is not allowed to issue an error in the example.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Yes, I also think it's not allowed. Answer revised.

Comment: I think by the spirit of the standard it should apply individually to the primary template and to each partial specialization. But I found a more convincing quote, `[res.general]/6.4`. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code is ill-formed, no diagnostic required (meaning the code is invalid, but compilers are not required to detect this fact).

This is caused by [`[temp.res.general]/6.4`](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res.general-6.4):

> The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> — a hypothetical instantiation of a template immediately following its definition would be ill-formed due to a construct that does not depend on a template parameter, ...